# Cannot calibrate my monitor & laptop

Tags: screen, color-management

I want to calibrate my laptop (Ubuntu 14.04) and monitor because they have slightly different colors, but the calibrate button is grayed out.

Why is that? How can I fix it?

Comment: I think you need to connect a calibration device (colorimeter or a spectrophotometer) to your laptop for the calibration to become avilable (this could be better explained in the UI)